# Sqlite and python timestamp

Tags: python, sqlite

I have this code in python 2.4:

```
import datetime, time, sqlite
def metodo(date):
        conn = sqlite.connect('dataBase.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO f values(?,?)", (3,date))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

end_date=datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 21, 0, 0)
print end_date

metodo(end_date)
```

and a sqlite database with int and TIMESTAMP

```
create table f(id int, time TIMESTAMP)
```

but i obtain this in python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prueba.py", line 13, in ?
metodo(end_date)
File "prueba.py", line 6, in metodo
c.execute("INSERT INTO f values(?,?)", (3,date))
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/sqlite/main.py", line 255, in execute
self.rs = self.con.db.execute(SQL % parms)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

---

This code run well. The problem is with timestamp:

```
import datetime, time, sqlite
def metodo(date):
        conn = sqlite.connect('dataBase.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO a values(%s)", date)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()


metodo("stringTest")
```

and a sqlite database with int and TIMESTAMP

```
create table a(test text)
```

Comment: what happens if you convert it to UNIX time before passing it to SqLite?

Comment: There is no `sqlite` module on Python 2.4 by default. The first snippet works fine with `sqlite3` (from stdlib) and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should parameterize it like this:

```
def metodo(date):
        conn = sqlite.connect('dataBase.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO a values(%s)", (date,))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) uses `'?'` parameter holders.